# Compiler directive (DEBUG) work wrong for publishing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have simple code with compiler directive in my WPF app:

```
#if (DEBUG)
                MySettings.Default.Host = "http://localhost:63372/";
#else
                MySettings.Default.Host = "http://example.com/";
#endif
```

All works fine in the Visual Studio. When I switch to Release or Debug then `Host` filled properly. But when I make publish, in the decompiler I see that `Host` is equal to `"http://localhost:63372/"` string.

Where is a problem?

[image: info]

Comment: How are you publishing?

Comment: @CodingGorilla: forgot to mention. I use the ClickOnce

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
#if (DEBUG)
                MySettings.Default.Host = "http://localhost:63372/";
#endif

#if (!DEBUG)
                MySettings.Default.Host = "http://example.com/";    
#endif
```

Comment: Logically this is exactly the same as what the OP is currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the anwser. When you publish with clickOnce it uses current selected mode. So, I need to switch to release and then click Publish.